# keep updating roles to allow using command from database

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm having a bot that users will go on and create a role when they first setup the bot, and then the roles will be saved into the database to be used later, I will save role `id` in the database
the process of how I'm planning to make the thing work is, I have a file called `roles.py` for example, nave this in there

```
#in my roles.py file

def get_admin():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()
    admin =c.execute("select admin from settings").fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return int(admin)
```

and on the file file where I'm running my bot at, I want to use the command everytime someone uses the role, so it gets the role from the database, like this:

```
@bot.slash_command()
@commands.has_role(roles.get_admin())
async def test(inter):
    await inter.response.send_message("hey")
```

But somehow it wouldn't work this way, looks like when the bot first starts, it gets whatever roles are on the database and doesn't update them, it uses the old role from the database
if I turn the bot off and on again, it would perfectly work, since it would update the roles, but is there a way to do it without turning it off and on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check is initialized and added at compile time, not every time that it is run. That means that the role will take effect when the bot just starts running, and then it will never change even if `roles.get_admin()` changes.

You'll need to make a custom check to update the role every single time (see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.check)).

```py
async def my_check(ctx):
    # call `roles.get_admin()` again each time this check runs, so it gets updated
    # it seems like `roles.get_admin()` returns the id
    # if you want to use the name instead, change `role.id` to `role.name`
    return roles.get_admin() in [role.id for role in ctx.author.roles]

@bot.slash_command()
@commands.check(my_check)
async def test(inter):
    await inter.response.send_message("hey")
```